# Polymorphic Relationships in ActiveAdmin Forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

I have an Active Admin form where I need to be able to update/add a polymorphic relationship to an object. I can get the form to display it, but it won't update the table with the polymorphic relationship. The models are Category and TargetArea and they both have Tags. Here is the model setup:

```
#category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end


#tag.rb
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :target_area
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :taggable
end

#Active Admin Form for Categories
permit_params :name, tags: []
form do |f|
  f.actions
    f.inputs 'Categories' do
    f.input :name
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :tags do |t|
        t.input :name
      end
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I want to be able to update and create new categories and add tags to the category in the form. I can't seem to find an example that does the same thing and this just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Still havn't found a working solution.